# How to find unique lines in a text file from command line?

Tags: command-line, cygwin

I would like to know how to extract a list of unique lines from a text file.
Preferably through Cygwin.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique" as a verb?

Answer (score 24):

sort -u file > new_file

Comment: You can pass stdin to `sort`, as well:  `grep -rnw '/path/to/files' | sort -u - > /tmp/out.txt`

Answer (score 19):

Your question is somewhat unclear. If you want to eliminate all duplicate lines from a text file you can do something like this:

```
cat file.txt | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Useless use of cat.  no cookie for you either.

Answer (score 5):

Since the original question referenced [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which is Windows specific, I'll mention that [Luis'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770199/how-to-find-unique-lines-in-a-text-file-from-command-line/770213#770213) answer works just as well using the [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) `sort`. I use the GNU ports off a USB key when I'm working on a machine that I don't want to install Cygwin on, or downloading and installing Cygwin seems like too heavy a solution for the problem I'm trying to solve.